# Mirror Modifier and spacing

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror-modifier

This is my first stab at using the mirror mod and I am have a weird issue. The eye in this case is mirrored but it's not in the correct place according to my ref image. I have done the red loop and it worked perfectly and made sure to take off the ability to select the ref material totally to avoid movement.Now the question is.

How do I move the mirror object to be in place or how do I correct my mistake otherwise?

[image]

Comment: By default the Mirror modifier mirrors with the 3D cursor as the centre. Your cursor is to the right of the centre line in your image which is causing the eye to be offset. You'll either need to reset the 3D cursor or move your reference image over so that it's centred relative to the 3D cursor. If you upload your blend file (https://pasteall.org/blend/ ) and paste the link here we can see what's going on. Since you have a reference image you'll need to pack your image into the Blend file via File > External Data > Pack resources and save it before uploading.

Comment: Thanks 

http://sendanywhe.re/W366CPLM

Here is the link

Comment: Small follow up. To the attached. 

I have not applied transforms and after I did the positioning is much better but still off

Comment: You can see the mirror axis (thin blue line) is not aligned with the center of your reference image. Move it slightly to the right

Comment: @Gorgious please see updated image. I re did this a few times to try and resolve my issue.

Comment: @JohnEason forgot to tag you

Comment: No problem. Are you sorted now?

Comment: @JohnEason 

No. I kind of gave up. 

I recreated this 5 times today with the same result. 

I figure I will try once more>

Comment: One thing I noticed with the file you uploaded (once I'd finally managed to download it...) is that you have the origin of the eye mesh near the centre of the eye. For the mirror modifier to work the origin must be at the 3D cursor, so select the eye mesh in Object mode and use the Object > Set Origin > Origin to 3D cursor menu option.

Comment: Still not aligned https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYYkj.png

Comment: Thank you all. 

It's resolved. Inches matter @Gorgious and thanks John

Comment: @JohnEason I'm a bit late to this party but since when does the _Mirror_ modifier by default use the 3D cursor as the center? By default it uses the object's origin and is set to  mirror on the X axis (which in this case would also be the local X axis, not global). So whatever was wrong with this model (cannot check since it wasn't uploaded on blend-exchange), the fact that the 3D cursor was a bit offset is not necessarily a problem for the _Mirror_ modifier... the origin is unfortunately not visible in the screenshot.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Only 6 months late! :^) I'm not sure what I was thinking when I said that! The object was actually off-centre from the origin as Gorgious showed in his comment so correcting that should have sorted the problem.

Comment: Yeah, I just stumbled across this because I answered another of the OP's question and just looked if there were more unanswered questions.